# PowerGUI "Root Element is Missing" While launch

Tags: windows, powershell, powergui

I get an error while launching powergui editor and launch fails everytime with error:

Root Element is missing.

Any suggesstions here, while i am still trying to figure out the solution using multiple forums for powergui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for this issue basically do the following steps:

**First Solution:**:

1. Run -> %appdata% (This takes you to "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming")
2. Look for PowerGUI profile folder ("Quest Software"). and Rename it to something like "Quest Software_old"
3. Now go to add remove programs and select Uninstall/Modify for "Quest PowerGUI" program.
4. Select the option Repair in Wizard and run it.

**Second Solution:** (This Works if you have used powerGUI script editor because at that time it saves your configuration's backup)

1. Run -> %appdata% (This takes you to "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming")
2. Go into folder "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Quest Software\PowerGUI"
3. Rename "Config.xml" to "Config.xml_corrupted"
4. Rename "Config.xml.back" to "Config.xml"
5. Relaunch powergui.

**references:** http://www.powergui.org/thread.jspa?threadID=5885

The solution is for Windows 8 Operating system while it might work on other windows operating systems too.

Just thought this might light up someone's day. Have a good day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall PowerGUI, deleted all files under my_profile\appdata\Local\Quest Software\PowerGUI and reinstall again.

Chances are your config file has gone corrupted.

Comment: Hi Travis, You are right my profile is corrupted but the folder which matters here is my_profile\appdata\Roming, I was breaking my head against renaming and reinstall in "Local" folder and it did not work. With every reinstall i got the same error till finally i used the second solution i posted in my solution.  Key folder is %appdata% here. Thanks for response.